# How to declare a delegate that can take an enum which is not known until runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, delegates

I have a client application that uses classes (and enums) from an external dll which is loaded at runtime and reflected. I know what methods I am expecting to find in the dll and what I am expecting its enums to be called.

I would like to create a delegate that I can use in the client application and which is created from the reflected method at runtime. This approach works when the delegate just has "standard" types, but how can I get this to work if the dll method takes an enum? I can't declare the enum in the delegate as an `object` since it's a value type, trying the `Enum` or `int` does not seem to work either. Is there a way around this? Any help gratefully received!

```
// e.g. external code
namespace test2 
{
    public static class test2
    {
        public static int calc(int a, int b, testEnum c)
        {
            if (c == testEnum.add) return a + b;
            else return a - b;
        }

        public static int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    public enum testEnum
    {
        add, subtract
    }
}

// my client code
namespace test1
{
    public class TestClient
    {
        private static Assembly _assembly;

        public static void SetUp()
        {
            const string externalDll = ".../test2.dll";

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(externalDll);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
            _assembly = assembly;
        }

        private delegate int _add(int a, int b);
        private _add add;

        private delegate int _calc(int a, int b, ??? c); // nothing works here
        private _calc calc;

        public void Run()
        {
            SetUp();
            add = GetExpectedFunction<_add>("add");
            int three = add(1, 2); // OK

            calc = GetExpectedFunction<_calc>("calc"); // not OK

            // intended usage
            var reflectedEnum = ReflectMe("testEnum", "add");
            int threeAgain = calc(1, 2, reflectedEnum); 
        }

        public static T GetExpectedFunction<T>(string functionName) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate))) throw new ApplicationException("GetExpectedFunction must return a delegate!");
                var foundMethod = _assembly.GetType("test2.test2").GetMethod(functionName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                return (T)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), foundMethod);  
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // "Error binding to target method!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the source of `ReflectMe` method? What you are trying to do it very tricky, but it's not impossible.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't written that bit yet :) I just put that in to show what I was trying to do. The problem is that I can't get the delegate on the call to `GetExpectedFunction<_calc>("calc");`

Comment: Try `Func<int,int,int,int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a delegate with `object` type to a method taking an `enum` by creating, at runtime, a dynamic method call with LINQ `Expression`, and adding data conversions for parameters whose types don't match:

```
public static T GetExpectedFunction<T>(string functionName) where T : class {
    try {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate))) throw new ApplicationException("GetExpectedFunction must return a delegate!");
        var foundMethod = Type.GetType("test2.test2").GetMethod(functionName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var inv = typeof(T).GetMethod("Invoke");
        var parameters = inv.GetParameters().Zip(foundMethod.GetParameters(), (a, b) => new {
            PassedIn = a.ParameterType
        ,   Reflected = b.ParameterType
        ,   Parameter = Expression.Parameter(a.ParameterType)
        }).ToList();
        if (parameters.All(p => p.PassedIn == p.Reflected)) {
            // Bind directly
            return (T)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), foundMethod);  
        }
        var call = Expression.Call(foundMethod, parameters.Select(
            p => p.PassedIn==p.Reflected
        ?   (Expression)p.Parameter
        :   Expression.Convert(p.Parameter, p.Reflected)
        ));
        return (T) (object) Expression.Lambda(typeof(T), call, parameters.Select(p => p.Parameter)).Compile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // "Error binding to target method!"
        return null;
    }
}
```

This implementation pairs up types from the reflected and the delegate methods (see `parameters` variable), and creates `ParameterExpression` objects for types that come from the delegate. Then it checks if all parameter types match up (the `parameters.All(...)` part). This is an optimization for situations when conversions are unnecessary.

If at least one conversion is necessary, the code creates a method call that substitutes the original parameter expressions with conversion expressions where types do not match up, creates a lambda of the requested delegate type, compiles it, and returns it to the caller.

For your code this dynamic method would look like this:

```
int dynamic_method(int a, int b, object c) {
    return test2.test2(a, b, (testEnum)c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution, you have to create faked Enum (it will be better if you create the exact enum), then you will pass as integer like this:

```
   private delegate int _add(int a, int b);
    private _add add;

    private delegate int _calc(int a, int b, FakedEnum c); // faked enum here
    private _calc calc;

    public enum FakedEnum
    {

    }

    public void Run()
    {
        SetUp();
        add = GetExpectedFunction<_add>("add");
        int three = add(1, 2); // OK

        calc = GetExpectedFunction<_calc>("calc"); // it will be ok
    var result=    calc(4, 6, (FakedEnum)0);
        // intended usage
       // var reflectedEnum = ReflectMe("testEnum", "add");
        //int threeAgain = calc(1, 2, reflectedEnum);
    }
```

Comment: 1) You could even use a plain `int` instead of the fake enum. `Func<int,int,int,int>` or `delegate int _calc(int a, int b, int c)` work as well. 2) Note that the underlying type of the enum must match. By default it's an `int`, so this code will work in most cases.

Comment: @CodesInChaos it will not work with int, object, or dynamic, you can test!

Comment: I tested it with an `int`, and it worked. It works for the same reason your code does: `int` and all enums with the underlying type of `int` are compatible as far as the CLR is concerned. LinqPad code: `void Main()
{
 var a=(Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>),this,"A");
 a(1);
}

void A(E e)
{
 e.Dump();
}

enum E
{
}`

Comment: hey you're right, i've not test with int, I know the underline data of enum is integer or byte, .., but that guy who asked question said he already tried with int but didn't worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Use dynamic keyword to declare your delegate parameter:

```
private delegate int _calc(int a, int b, dynamic c);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original question that I tried this without success. Did it work for you?